# How to edit my list?

Tags: c#, list, generics

```
public static List<Client> GetAllClients()
    {
        return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client(e: 1, d: 1998, a: "Tom Johnson", b: "+32273", c: "Honda Civic"),
            new Client("sarah jackson", "88777793483254459", "subaru Forester", 2005, 2),
            new Client("jack thompson", "+37083227359", "audi 100", 1992),
            new Client("tomas jonauskas", "+37183227359", "tesla model s", 2014, 3),
            new Client("egle tomiene", "+00483227359", "volkswagen golf", 2010),
            new Client("jonas petrauskas", "8482359", "peugeot 206", 2000, 2)

        };
    }
```

Pretty straight forward question.
This method returns a new generated list, but if I change some of the objects in other class I get the same list. Is there a way to return an edited list without destroying this method? Thanks.

This is the regex I try to validate, but the output is the same list Whatever I try to change.

```
    internal class Regexes
{
    public static void ValidatePhone()
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"Someregex");
        for (int i = 0; i < Program.GetAllClients().Count; i++)
        {
            if (!regex.IsMatch(Program.GetAllClients()[i].Phone))            
                Program.GetAllClients()[i].Phone = "[Invalid phone number]";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for asking such a newbie question.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "return an edited list".  When code calls this method and gets back a list, that code can make whatever changes it wants to that list.  What are you trying to do and in what way is your code not working?

Comment: @David Added some code. Hope it helps.

Comment: `Program.GetAllClients()` this is returning new list each time. at each iteration. so you have to save the list before calling this method and do the changes to that list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your objective, you want to have a single copy of the clients list and every edit will be made on the same unique list. As it is now, everytime you call GetAllClients, you recreate the list thus, every change made from other code is lost.

You need to use a static initial variable of your list. 
When someone calls `GetAllClients`, check if you have initialized the list. If yes, return the initialized list, if not, create the unique instance of the list and return it.

```
private static List<Client> _currentList = null;
public static List<Client> GetAllClients()
{
    if(_currentList == null)
        _currentList = new List<Client>
        {
            new Client(e: 1, d: 1998, a: "Tom Johnson", b: "+32273", c: "Honda Civic"),
            new Client("sarah jackson", "88777793483254459", "subaru Forester", 2005, 2),
            new Client("jack thompson", "+37083227359", "audi 100", 1992),
            new Client("tomas jonauskas", "+37183227359", "tesla model s", 2014, 3),
            new Client("egle tomiene", "+00483227359", "volkswagen golf", 2010),
            new Client("jonas petrauskas", "8482359", "peugeot 206", 2000, 2)

       };
    return _currentList;
}
```

Now, if some code changes the list that change is made on the same reference returned by `GetAllClients`, thus every call to GetAllClients receives the same modified copy.

Keep in mind that this is not thread safe.

With this change, you could also keep your existing code because the repetitive calls to `GetAllClients` will receive always the same list changed or not but, of course, it is a waste of time to continuosly call the `GetAllClients` as you do in your code. Just call it one time, store the result in a temporary variable and then do your work with the temporary variable that references the same list stored in the static variable.

```
public static void ValidatePhone()
{
    List<Clients> clients = Program.GetAllClients();
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"Someregex");
    for (int i = 0; i < clients.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!regex.IsMatch(clients[i].Phone))            
            clients[i].Phone = "[Invalid phone number]";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the same list each time you call `GetAllClients` because you are returning a new list with the same `Client`s. Your `ValidatePhone` method alters the list correctly but it's not *saved*. You are making a new list (With `Program.GetAllClients`) and leaved it alone to be garbage collected later. To access it at a later time, you need to reference the object (with a variable)  . You can modify your method as follows:

```
internal class Regexes
{
    public static void ValidatePhone()
    {
        List<Client> clientList = Program.GetAllClients();
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"Someregex");
        for (int i = 0; i < clientList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!regex.IsMatch(clientList[i].Phone))

                clientList[i].Phone = "[Netinkama ivestis]";
            }
        }

        //Console.WriteLine(clientList[1].Phone);
    }
}
```

This way you have referenced your "generated list" with the variable `clientList` and you can access it even if it is altered. You don't have to call the `GetAllClients` method each time.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you do this:

```
Program.GetAllClients()[i].Phone = "[Invalid phone number]";
```

You create an *entirely new* list, modify a value within it, and then don't do anything with it.  As soon as the `if` block completes, this new list goes away entirely.

Get the list *once* and store it in a variable:

```
var clients = Program.GetAllClients();
```

Then modify *that* list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < clients.Count; i++)
{
    if (!regex.IsMatch(clients[i].Phone))
         clients[i].Phone = "[Netinkama ivestis]";
    }
}
```

Afterward, whatever you want to do with the `clients` is up to you.  Display it, save it, something else, etc.  But the point is that you need to store a value in a variable in order to use that value at a later time.